# Navbar collapse button and navbar links don't align properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've pasted all of the relevant html/css here: http://www.bootply.com/6YQGagMczD

My problem is that when in responsive mode, the button to open the navigation menu doesn't seem to align properly with the centered navigation menu items. It's off by what appears to be a few pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have padding-left of 5 pixels on the menu, but no margin on the menu icon itself.

What you're missing is:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

I've created a new Fiddle showcasing this [here](http://www.bootply.com/CtnMDRb2Y4).

**EDIT**

In your new fiddle, the misalignment comes from the fact that `.navbar-toggle` (created by Bootstrap) has a default margin-right of 15px. You'll need to override this by resetting it to 0, as such:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Here's a new [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/sdZfBCjagb).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, that was my attempt to fix the alignment that I forgot to remove. I've modified the Fiddle, and the new link is http://www.bootply.com/6YQGagMczD

Comment: @Max -- No worries; I've updated my answer to cover this :)